# Excel seems to be bypassing initial IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

```
=IF(COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,AND("Bulwark","Hard to Kill")),(WL*3)+(SM*6)+35,IF(COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,"Bulwark"),(WL*3)+(SM*6)+25,IF(COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,"Hard to Kill"),(WL*3)+(SM*6)+10,IF((WL*3)+(SM*6)=0," ",(WL*3)+(SM*6)))))
```

I need my sheet to search within a range (ADVANTAGES), first look for an instance of *both* criteria, if false, search for an instance of *each* criteria. All three scenarios would indivudally produce a different formula (WL and SM are named cells where user inputs a number). Finally, if the cell would equal 0, it should be blank (which is what the last IF statement does).

For some reason, this isn't working. When I put *both* criteria in the referenced range, it returns the completed formula for only one of the criteria (the first of the two). It's as if it's bypassing the first logical test with the AND statement.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a job for SUMPRODUCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AND is in the wrong place. Try:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,"Bulwark"),COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,"Hard to Kill")),(WL*3)+(SM*6)+35,IF(COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,"Bulwark"),(WL*3)+(SM*6)+25,IF(COUNTIF(ADVANTAGES,"Hard to Kill"),(WL*3)+(SM*6)+10,IF((WL*3)+(SM*6)=0," ",(WL*3)+(SM*6)))))
```